# Android Gradle: How to publish all build variants to artifactory

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, artifactory, aar, android-productflavors

So I have this android library that I have created with different build flavors. The build.gradle looks something like this:

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion 21
  buildToolsVersion "21.0.1"

  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.mylibrary"
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 20
    versionName = "mylibrary"
    versionCode = 102
}

productFlavors {
    gcm {

    }

    amazon {

    }

    ua {

    }
  }

}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.+'

  gcmCompile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.11'
  amazonCompile files('libs/amazon-device-messaging-1.0.1.jar')
  uaCompile files('libs/urbanairship-lib-4.0.4.jar')
}
```

How do I get "artifactoryPublish" task to publish all 3 of the build aars?

Comment: I sort of solved it by adding:

  android {
    publishNonDefault true
  }

Comment: Does not generate a pom file in my case.  So transitive dependencies don't work.  Any ideas?